# Makefile.inc does not exist plexe-veins

Tags: makefile, omnet++, veins, plexe-veins, plexe

I am new to command line and have followed all the threads related to make including downloading mingw and adding to both my system and user paths. I still get this error when I run mingw32-make.exe:

```
$ mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'E:/src/plexe-veins/src'
makefile:147: *** Config file '/e/src/omnetpp-5.3/Makefile.inc' does not exist -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configf                             ilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/src/plexe-veins/src'
makefile:12: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have double checked if omnetpp-5.3 bin is in my path and yet I get the same error. Could anyone be so kind to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your path variable? (`echo $PATH`) 'Does the mentioned file exist on your system?

Comment: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;D:\Matlab\runtime\win64;D:\Matlab\bin;E:\Matlab installation files\runtime\win64;E:\Matlab installation files\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\program files (x86)\skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Halid Jay Kobbie\Desktop\sumos\sumo-0.31.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\DLR\Sumo\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\DLR\Sumo\tools\;E:\src\omnetpp-5.3-src-windows\omnetpp-5.3\bin;

Comment: There are too many characters so I will have to post them in batches

Comment: E:\src\omnetpp-5.3-src-windows\omnetpp-5.3\@OMNETPP_BIN_DIR@\utils;E:\jayprogramfiles\Git\cmd;E:\jayprogramfiles\Git\bin;C:\mingw64\bin;E:\src\omnetpp-5.3\bin;E:\src\mingw32\bin;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;E:\jayprogramfiles\mingw64\bin;E:\jayprogramfiles\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin;E:\jayprogramfiles\mingw64;E:\src\plexe-veins-plexe-2.0

Comment: BTW thanks so much for your speedy response. That should be the whole list of variables.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch. The makefile uses paths as specified under msys (/e/src...) yet it seems you are running make under cmd (E:\src...). This won't work as make won't find the msys paths. If you created the makefile under msys (most likely as a result of `configure`) you will have to run make there as well

Comment: Again thanks for your help, I am not sure I understand what you mean by msys though. Sorry I am completely new to this.

Comment: I open up git bash from the dir of interest and run the configure file as you stated, I am able to get through the configure stage but make doesn't work from the same bash. I am not sure if that's what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things involved: mingw, msys and git for windows.

- MSYS is a minimal unix-like environment featuring a shell and some tools. It uses an abstraction layer to make unix tools work under windows
- MinGW is a GCC distribution to produce native windows binaries
- Git for windows itself bundles msys to use for as terminal environment

The "git bash" from the context menu opens a terminal which itself runs a a stripped down msys (enough to interact with git). If you have mingw in your path it might autodetect it and includes it.

Now to your problem: The mingw32-make is meant to be used under native win32 - not the msys (git) prompt (it can be used, but might have shortcomings). You will need the msys make for that. The mingw installer offers the option for a msys base system - get that, it should include make. When installed open the msys prompt (not the git bash) and navigate to your folder, run configure again and try `make`.

Also make sure you are using the installed mingw gcc - try `which gcc` and see if the path you get matches the installed path.

Comment: Thanks so much, Loebl, I am just seeing this, let me try implementing what you have said. Fingers crossed. I appreciate. I will update my post as soon as I have positive results or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Loebl, using msys does the trick. I am appreciative of your help.

Comment: If it answers your question please mark it as an accepted answer, so that future users know it worked in at least your case.