# Makefile.inc does not exist in OMNeT++ but it actually exists

Tags: makefile, omnet++

I'm a new learner of OMNeT++. When I tried to build the project, the software warns me that " `Makefile.inc` does not exist, add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to `Makefile.inc`. " However, the Makefile.inc exists.

I have added the bin to the path and set OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE as the path of `Makefile.inc`. I also tried the ways to use the msys mingw to excute `make`, which is mentioned in the post of [jaykobbiejnr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872060/makefile-inc-does-not-exist-plexe-veins)but I got the warning again.

Comment: Be sure to `export` the `OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE` variable or to set it on the `make` command line.  If you just assign it at the shell prompt then it is known to that shell process only, not to any processes it launches.

Comment: Overall, though, there is insufficient information in the question confidently diagnose the problem.

Comment: Some meaningful information is useful if you expect your question to be answered, like platform, omnet version, and a step by step description what you did. You are new here, but when you ask a question, consider that others must be able to REPRODUCE your issue...

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks for your answer. I eventually solved the problem by removing the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE from the PATH and variables. I'll make sure to make a clear description and provide enough information next time.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST use the provided mingwenv.cmd command to execute all omnetpp related commands. i.e. always work in the console (even the IDE must be started from there)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructive suggestion. I finally solved the problem by removing the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE from the PATH and variables.